# AVAsset it not working with HLS Streaming file

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

I try to play a m3u8 file and a mp3 file simultaneously:

```
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://XXX.de/XXX.mp3"];
AVAsset *audioAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:audioURL];

NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://XXX.de/XXX.m3u8"];
AVAsset *videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];


NSError *error;

AVMutableComposition* mixAsset = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

AVMutableCompositionTrack* audioTrack = [mixAsset addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error: &error];

AVMutableCompositionTrack* videoTrack = [mixAsset addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error: &error];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:mixAsset];

movie = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

but it is not working. I get the following error:

```
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

With a mp4-Files it is working but not with m3u8 file.
The apple docs say that avasset works with local or remote URLs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset?language=objc

i wonder if m3u8 is basically not working.

Comment: Hi, We have the exact same problem as you have. I wonder if you have found a solution to this since it's been quite a long time.